# Spinner a String y almacenarlo en fire base

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase, spinner

amigos estoy haciendo un mantenedor para agregar un producto a una base de datos de firebase, en esta interfaz necesito que el spinner tenga guardadas algunas opciones como por ejemplo en el spinner de "marca" almacenar distintas marcas de calzados ej. "nike - puma - adidas - etc" y que al momento de guardar el producto se almacene con la opcion seleccionada en firebase... la idea es guardar "marca" y "tipo de calzado" como un String me podrian ayudar por favor desde ya muchas gracias.

[image: interfaz agregar producto]

Comment: Que es lo que intentaste para guardar los datos en el spinner?

Comment: https://luismasdev.com/cargar-datos-en-un-spinner-android/   esto habia visto para intentar hacer

Comment: bien, el sitio de stack es para dudas sobre codigo que hayas hecho, donde pones lo que intentaste y nosotros vemos que error tienes para guiarte, la idea no es que hagamos el desarrollo nosotros de la feature. Ese tutorial que linkeas esta bien para cargar un spinner, no deberias tener problemas

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo, lo que quieres hacer sería lo siguiente.

```
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String marca = "";

    //Lista de marcas
    List<String> marcas = new ArrayList<String>();
    marcas.add("Rebook");
    marcas.add("Adidas");
    marcas.add("Nike");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, marcas);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    marca = marcas.get(position);

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
```

Para guardar el valor del spinner;

```
    private void guardar() {
    Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<>();
    info.put("marca", marca);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("nombre_coleccion")
    .add(info)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"BAD",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
}
```